# WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher

Tags: ruby, windows-10, gem, cucumber, testes-automatizados

Estou tentando executar meus testes automatizados porém acontece este erro relacionado ao ANSICON. Já tentei realizar a instalação no meu Windows 10, mas ele não permite.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Traduzido da resposta original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749307/3861347

1. Fazer o download do Ansicon https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads, descompactar dentro de um diretório sem espaços.
2. Abrir o prompt de comando e navegar até a pasta que você descompactou.
3. Agora, navegar até a pasta da arquitetura do seu sistema operacional x86 ou x64 e instalar globalmente ex: (D:\Cucumber\ansi160\x64)
4. Digite `ansicon.exe –i` ou `ansicon -i` e aperte enter
5. Agora qualquer programa que vá precisar printar as cores do ANSI vão funcionar.

Pelo seu erro você está na pasta da arquitetura errada. Veja novamente o seu sistema operacional e repita os passos acima.